# Distributed Hbase failed to start, with error info: Server is not running yet

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to set up a distributed Hbase based on Hadoop, with one namenode on my Ubuntu 20.04 and three datanodes on localhost and two VMs. All went well when I started Hadoop and Hbase, jps info on the namenode:

```
44499 DataNode
44291 NameNode
45012 ResourceManager
45380 NodeManager
40408 QuorumPeerMain
46521 HRegionServer
44748 SecondaryNameNode
46188 HMaster
48733 Jps
```

jps info on the datanode:

```
3968 QuorumPeerMain
5155 Jps
4980 HRegionServer
4782 NodeManager
4638 DataNode
```

But when I tried hbase shell and wanted to see tables using 'list', the error info revealed that Hbase didn't start successfully actually ...

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                            

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ServerNotRunningYetException: Server is not running yet
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkServiceStarted(HMaster.java:2923)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.isMasterRunning(MasterRpcServices.java:1182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:318)

For usage try 'help "list"'

Took 8.6983 seconds
```

In logs, I found the error:

```
2021-01-12 09:33:40,124 INFO  [main-SendThread(pro2:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server pro2/192.168.122.113:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

After searching I thought the problem might lie in zookeeper so I went to see zk logs, but found none errors, which troubles me.

This is my hbase-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://jyy-lenovo-legion:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>

  <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>jyy-lenovo-legion,pro1,pro2</value>
  </property>

  <!--
  property>
    <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>./tmp</value>
  </property
  -->
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

And my zoo.cfg:

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/usr/local/zookeeper/zkData
clientPort=2181
server.1=pro1:2888:3888
server.2=pro2:2888:3888
```

I am quite new to Hbase, Hadoop, etc. Could anyone figure out what is wrong? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use older version of Hadoop, Hbase and JDK 8.
Example:

1. Hadoop: 2.10.x
2. Hbase:1.6.x
3. JDK 8.

You could find the compatibility of Hadoop and Hbase version from this [link](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#basic.prerequisites)

After that, if there is any error, you could try this command:

> find $HBASE_HOME/ -type f -name 'htrace-core*' -ls

If you see two results from this command, delete one and start Hadoop, Hbase again.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar` under bhase and turn off the safe mode of Hadoop. You can execute the (`hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`) command to shut down, and then restart hbase